# Dell P2210 - broken display info and bad resolution

Tags: xorg, dell, display-resolution

I have a problem using my Dell P2210 display on DVI-D port. First of all, when using VGA port everything is correct with except of image quality - there is problem with flickering. I don't know whether it's a problem of cable or docking station of my laptop, so I wanted to try another, digital port.

Unfortunately, when I connect my display to DVI port, my Ubuntu does not get display information (Unknown display) and shows limited lists of possible resolutions. For now, the most reasonable option is 1280x800 although this screen supports 1680x1050.

I tried to manually add resolution configuration with xorg:

```
$ cvt 1680 1050 60
# 1680x1050 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.76MA) hsync: 65.29 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
asmox@asmox-nb-ubuntu:~$ xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
asmox@asmox-nb-ubuntu:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 800, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     59.91 +  39.94  
DP-0 connected primary 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00 +
   1600x900      59.82  
   1400x900      59.88  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.96    59.80  
   1280x800      59.91*   59.81  
   1280x720      59.86    59.74  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x576      59.90    59.82  
   960x540       59.82    59.63  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   800x450       59.82  
   700x450       59.88  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   640x400       59.98    59.88  
   640x360       59.86    59.83  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.82    59.63  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1680x1050_60.00 (0x2da) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
asmox@asmox-nb-ubuntu:~$ xrandr --addmode DP-0 1680x1050_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  36
```

Just to keep things clear, my external display is on DP-0, and Screen 0 is probably native display of my laptop.

So far I tried to edit resolution info via `nvidia-settings`, but I wasn't able to perform manual changes. I also tried to get some info from `get-edid` and I even got some results, but I have no idea what to do with it:

```
asmox@asmox-nb-ubuntu:~$ parse-edid < monitor0
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "�"
    ModelName "�"
    VendorName "LGD"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 0 of 2010
    # EDID version 1.4
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 340 190
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "false"
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 139.50 1920 1968 2000 2096 1080 1083 1088 1111 -hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" 93.00 1920 1968 2000 2096 1080 1083 1088 1111 -hsync -vsync 
EndSection
asmox@asmox-nb-ubuntu:~$ sudo get-edid > monitor0
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No byte reading on this bus...
Problem requesting slave address: Bad file descriptor
No byte reading on this bus...
Problem requesting slave address: Bad file descriptor
2 potential busses found: 2 3
Will scan through until the first EDID is found.
Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one.
128-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 2
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
```

In the end, I considered to prepare manually `xorg.conf` file, but I'd avoid it if there is another option because I'm afraid I may completely break displaying on my working laptop.

Can you tell me please if there is any solution I could use directly on my display? If I understand correctly, there is some memory section in my P2210 with lacking information about possible resolutions - can I somehow add them again?